# Sharepoint Development Environment Setup Problems

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, setup

I am having major problems setting up a Sharepoint 2010 development environment (for home use).

I have the following setup.

HP Laptop (6 GB Ram, i5 processor, Windows 7 Home Premium, vs2010 professional sp1, sql server express 2008 r2)

The first route i tried was to download the vhd and run it using windows server 2008 r2, but after doing some research it became clear that
this would not be very performant as i do not have enough ram (most people say more than 8gb is best).

I then came across the http://blog.mikehacker.net/2010/08/26/sharepoint-2010-development-environment/ post which looked like a better option for me.

I tried installing Sharepoint 2010 foundation but got a message saying something like 'Can only install on Windows Server r2'.  I then looked
about and found that it cant be installed in 'Home Premium' edition (there are some hacks that can achieve this).

I am now very confused, what option do i choose?

How do i move forward?  Would Cloudshare do what i want?

Have you get any tips/online resources on how to progress?

Hope you can help.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/45712/627 ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. what template do i use? i noticed the foundation with dev tools, but no sp server with dev tools?

Comment: I would basically suggest using CloudShare, it's very easy to set up :)

Comment: if you have your heart set on windows 7, follow Gavin's link below, but just know, installing on Windows 7, while technically possible, is tedious, time consuming, and the least realistic devlopment experience.

Comment: @Derek - didn't have much of a problem with it myself. Sure its got a few steps but not that hard if you read and follow.

Comment: @eirikb and Cloudshare - thats OK if you don't want one click deployment or debugging but I couldn't imagine doing any serious dev like that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx) that walks you through this process